# Has agency law been tested against LLM backed agents?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agency

As more and more companies replace humans with large language model backed generative AIs (e.g. ChatGPT), I was curious to know if there have been any lawsuits (or compelling legal papers) addressing whether principals are bound by the "hallucinations" of their AI.

For the uninitiated, AI hallucinations are a euphemism for LLMs' propensity for [bullshit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Bullshit).

I'm in the US, but the question applies to any jurisdiction that uses agency theory.

**EDIT for clarification**

I wanted to clarify this a little.

I'm looking beyond just direct interactions with ChatGPT and OpenAI. Many companies are adopting LLM systems to create virtual customer support systems that can field their customers' questions.

What I'm really asking is: if such an AI-backed virtual support agent makes and assertion or promise or commitment due to sloppy LLM tuning (for instance), would this carry the same weight as if it were a human agent making the same assertion, promise or commitment?

Comment: Another path to consider is product liability law, since the AI companies are offering a "product", though there are ample disclaimers that would defeat any lawsuit based on "Your product said that...".

Comment: @user6726 you mean the "You agree to pay our legal fees in case your conduct damages us" clause, right?

Answer (score 2):

The potential exists in [Walters v. OpenAI](https://www.courthousenews.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/walters-openai-complaint-gwinnett-county.pdf), where OpenAI's program allegedly defamed Walters by publishing proveably falsehoods. Since Walters is a "public figure" (a talk show host), Walters will have to prove malice in the falsehood, but programs are legally devoid of "intent". The company itself had no awareness of what its program was doing. The current courtlistener stack on the federal branch of this case is [here](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/67617826/walters-v-openai-llc/) (OpenAI moved for removal to federal courts, they are still discussing the matter).

Comment: Wouldn't reckless disregard to whether the statements are false apply here? At least wrt to OAI's role in the matter?

Comment: @Dancrumb reckless disregard requires intent too

Comment: Their intent was to use the AI. If I use a gun to hammer a nail into a piece of wood, and there's a gunshot that kills you, then I don't need intent to kill you. Intent to use the hammer in an inappropriate way is enough.

Answer (score 1):

### Agency law is irrelevant

ChatGPT is not a legal person so it cannot be an agent. Any defamatory material it produces is product Ed by OpenAI directly - no agent involved.